# Windows Forms database auto generate ID column using LINQ

Tags: c#, database, linq

Created an application to insert data into the database using LINQ. I kept the ID column in the database. I am looking for guidance on how to have the ID column automatically add the next ID number each time a new entry is made into the data base?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Week4_2_
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        LinqsqlinsertdataDataContext objcontxt = new LinqsqlinsertdataDataContext();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void buttonInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//Inserts Records
        {
            using (objcontxt = new LinqsqlinsertdataDataContext())
            {
                TblSoccer name = new TblSoccer
                {
                    FirstName = txtFirstName.Text,
                    LastName = textBox2.Text,
                    Address = textBox1.Text,
                    Id = textBoxID.Text
                };

                objcontxt.TblSoccers.InsertOnSubmit(name);
                objcontxt.SubmitChanges();
            }

            getAllRecords();
        }

        private void getAllRecords() //Show all records
        {
            using (objcontxt = new LinqsqlinsertdataDataContext())
            {
                dataGridView1.DataSource = objcontxt.TblSoccers;
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            getAllRecords();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A database provides already that functionality. Have a look [here](https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-define-an-auto-increment-primary-key-in-sql-server/).

Answer (score 0):

In `LinqToSQL`, it requires primary key to insert or update the row in the Table. So your `ID` Column will be `PK` and `Identity` auto incremented column.

In `DBML`, you have to select your `ID` Column go to properties and set below properties:

`Auto Generated Value` : true and `Auto-Sync` : OnInsert